# CLion Nova code formatting: new scope on the same line as previous scope

Tags: c++, clion, code-formatting

When i format c++ code in clion it puts new scope { at the same line as the previous } of an if statement for example.

what i want:

```
if (...) {
...
}

{
// Some Code
}
```

what it does:

```
if (...) {
...
} {
// Some Code
}
```

It's super annoying and i don't know how to fix it. Any ideas on how to fix it?

I tried to edit code style for C++ but didn't find the related option to change it.

Comment: Quite possible there won't be any option for that, because no one really writes scopes that are not part of something (aside from toy examples for how lifetimes work). Why do you need it?

Comment: I just saw it in an advent of code solution (i am new to c++) to separate part 1 and part 2 variables from interfering with each other and a way to organize the code.

Comment: I've just been doing `do{ ..} while(false);`

@Yksisarvinen I can think of  use-cases where you want a destructor to be called, something like `{ Lock lock{}; write(data); }`

Comment: @krico A great place to introduce a `ThreadSafeWrite` function (or whatever the name would be) ;)